# Checking for a templated static method via concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I want to write a concept that checks if the type has a static method called `foo`. That method will have a templated parameter (the function will be called multiple times later with different parameter types).

Because of that templated parameter, it's quite difficult to check it. For the start, I thought I only check if there is a member at all with that name.

The following code compiles with Clang, but doesn't compile with GCC, because it cannot resolve the address of the overloaded function `T::foo`.

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept HasFoo = requires { T::foo; };

class Bar {
public:
    template <typename T>
    static void foo(T t);
};

static_assert(HasFoo<Bar>);
```

How do you correctly check for the existence of a templated static method (working in Clang and GCC)?
And ideally, can you even check more than this? Like checking if the return type is `void`, or if it is callable.

One way would be to include the templated type into the concept, but as I want to use the method with multiple different types.
So checking with only one type, like in the following code, is not enough.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename T2>
concept HasFoo = requires { T::template foo<T2>; };

static_assert(HasFoo<Bar, int>);
```

Comment: if Bar satsfies `HasFoo<Bar, int>` doesn't that tell you that it has a templated static function called `Foo`? and when you use any type inside a function / class, then `HasFoo<Bar, T>`

Comment: "*as I want to use the method with multiple different types.*" But what *are* those types? Could they be any types, or is there some constraint on what those types will be? What is the template code you trying to constrain, and what is the meaning of `foo` within that code? Doesn't `foo` know what the type(s) will be? Don't treat concepts like a base class function, where you force the user to conform to an exact signature.

Comment: @NicolBolas Not sure if this actually help with the question. In my application I try to do some policy-based design. There is a main algorithm. That main algorithm takes the object from one policy, and modifies it with a policy using it's function `foo`. The idea behind it is, that I want to make multiple algorithm instances, that differ on the objects that it works on and differ on the exact implementation of the method `foo`. So the templated method depends on the template argument that it's called by from the algorithm (so indirectly by the other template arguments arguments).

Comment: I do have some constraints on template arguments, for the sake of the simplified example in the question we can just assume it's an integer type.

Comment: @StackDanny I guess I can just test something like `requires (int x) { { T::foo(x) } -> std::convertable_to<int>; }` and then just assume that if it works with one template, that it also works with other templates arguments (like `long`, `char`, ...).

Comment: Does `HasFoo` have real meaning? You really want all `Bar::foo<char>`/`Bar::foo<std::iostream>`/`Bar::foo<MyObj>`/`Bar::foo<int()>`/`Bar::foo<void*>`, ...

Comment: @Jarod42 It does have a real meaning. The types aren't related via inheritence/OOP. But I could describe the type for the `foo` method itself with a concept. However I don't think that it's possible for a compiler to check if all possible types that could somehow fit one concept can be used inside another concept.

Comment: So you want some hypothetic `requires (SomeConcept x) { { T::foo(x); }`. it is more meaningful. :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes. That would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do you correctly check for the existence of a templated static method (working in Clang and GCC)? And ideally, can you even check more than this? Like checking if the return type is void, or if it is callable.

> I do have some constraints on template arguments, for the sake of the simplified example in the question we can just assume it's an integer type.

To check if the class support a static template method `foo()` that is callable with an integer and return `void`, you can simply check

```
template <typename T>
concept HasFoo = std::is_same_v<decltype(T::foo(0)), void>;
```

If you also want to be sure that the `foo()` method is a template one, I suppose you can also check that converting `&T::foo` to different function pointer types you get different values, so (for example)

```
(    (void*)(&T::template foo<int>)
  != (void*)(&T::template foo<long>))
```

Combining the two requirements,

```
template <typename T>
concept HasFoo =    (    (void*)(&T::template foo<int>)
                      != (void*)(&T::template foo<long>))
                 && std::is_same_v<decltype(T::foo(0)), void>;
```

With

```
struct Bar1 
 { template <typename T> static void foo (T) {} };

struct Bar2 
 { static void foo (int) {} };   

struct Bar3
 { template <typename T> static T foo; };

template <typename T>
T Bar3::foo;

struct Bar4
 { template <typename T> static int foo (T) { return 0; } };
```

you have

```
static_assert(HasFoo<Bar1>);
static_assert(not HasFoo<Bar2>); // not because foo() isn't template
static_assert(not HasFoo<Bar3>); // not because foo isn't callable
static_assert(not HasFoo<Bar4>); // not becasue foo() return int
```

Comment: Thanks so far. It's not quite the solution that I was hoping for, but it's a good start. In my codebase the templated type is a lot more complicated than just an integer type. They are complicated, custom classes. But I can just try to call the function with one example, and see if that works, and maybe even check with a second one if it is templated or not (similar to your code).

Comment: I do have a concept for the parameter as well. Ideally I would want to say that the method takes a type of that concept as parameter. But I doubt that this would be possible at all, as there is no guarantee that one type (described only very high-level via a concept) uses another concept correctly in it's internal methods. I guess I just want more than is possible.